# How can an authenticated user has no password set in the asp.net core mvc template

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

When I create a asp.net core mvc project template with user auth added and I go to the ManageController.Index action:

```
 bool HasPassword = await _userManager.HasPasswordAsync(user)
```

it is asking the userManager service wether the logged in user has a password!

Is that a template bug? How can a logged in user has no password?

The ManageController is annotated with Authorize-Attribute...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if the application uses social authentication such as Facebook, Google, Twitter, Microsoft etc then the user may not have a local password. The user can add a local password later and then be able to login to the same account without using social authentication.

Comment: Thanks that would explain the UI efforts in the index.html.